# Pushing Android project with multiple module to BitBucket

Tags: android, git, module, repository, bitbucket

The problem is the Android Project which I have has in all 3 modules viz. 1 main & other supporting modules.
Currently I pushed the whole project to BitBucket which includes the modules too, but I'm confused if I should just push modules in different repos & not in a single repo like I have did.
If different repos is the best way to go head, then how should I link all the 3 repos to represent as a single project.

Answer (score 2):

If it is one Android project then you should probably use [submodules](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-submodule). Read this tutorial to know more about how to create submodules:

https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules

Then you can use

```
git submodule foreach git pull
```

To pull all submodules recursively or

```
git pull --recurse-submodules
```

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you to create another Bitbucket repos for each supporting module then you could use git submodules to link them with your main project or just upload the artifacts to a maven repo like jcenter, sonatype or bintray, then you can compile they as dependencies in `build.gradle`. I prefer the second option.

Git submodule:

http://blogs.atlassian.com/2013/03/git-submodules-workflows-tips/

Comment: I like the idea of making it maven repo, etc. I did a bit of research & got confused in selecting in which I should use `Git Submodule` or `Git Subtree` or `maven repo`.
Just to help in decision my both modules would be getting updated very rarely. And I want them fetched when project is cloned & if changes are made to the module, it should be fetched. 
Let me know which one seems the perfect while I keep on my research.